# MySQL keeps crashing at unknown intervals

Tags: mysql, php, innodb

```
Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source                                                                         distribution
160130 08:29:38 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
160130 08:29:38 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
160130  8:29:39  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
160130  8:29:39  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: pthread_create returned 11
160130 08:29:39 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid     ended
160130 18:21:35 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from     /var/lib/mysql
160130 18:21:35  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
160130 18:21:35  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
160130 18:21:35  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
160130 18:21:35  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 818060756
160130 18:21:35 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160130 18:21:35 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

I do not know what this means. Is it that MySQL crashed because of a log file? I don't think so. Do I need to modify some config files?

Comment: I found this in the /var/log/messages file: Out of memory: Kill process 13477 (mysqld) score 93 or sacrifice child. Now, since it is out of memory, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Your server is running out of memory so badly it has to start randomly killing processes to survive.

You can either get more RAM, or reduce the amount you are using.  The 'top' command will show you all the running processes and how much memory they are using.  'free -m' will show you how much RAM you have and how much you are using.  Remove processes and services that you don't need.

MySQL can be tweaked to use less RAM at the cost of caching less and running slower.  There are plenty of guides out there on which options to set and their effects.  Apache or most other services that are running will have similar guides for tweaking them for low memory systems when necessary - again often at a performance cost.